# creating grid content with repeated array keys

Tags: php, for-loop

I have 15 elements and I want to order them using for() like this;

> 1 2 3
>   2 3 1
>   3 1 2
>   1 2 3
>   2 3 1

I tried;

```
for($i=0;$i<=15;$i++){
    $a = 1;
if($a==1){
    $a=($i%3)+1;
}elseif($a==2){
    $a=(($i+1)%3);
}else{
    $a=(($i+2)%3);
}
    echo $a." ";
}
```

output is;

> 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1 2 3 1

repeating 1-2-3

rule is simple;
there should be 3 keys in row and a key can not be used in same row again.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 1;
for($count=0; $count <= 5; $count++){
    $k = 0;
    for($j = $i; $j < 4; $j++){
         echo $j. ' ';
        $k++;
    }
    if($k < 3){
        if($k == 1) $k = 3;
        for($j = 1; $j < $k; $j++){
            echo $j.' ';
        }
    }
    echo '</br>';
    $i++;
    if($i > 3) $i = 1;
}
```

Comment: Opps, that creates 3 columns for each elements.(So I get total 45 elements) I have total 15 elements and assign numbers for them as above. Sorry for mistelling.

Comment: @bencagri I'm not clear about your requirements, sorry for that!